# Getting error from Flutter "No Signature Of Method"

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, methods, signature

It says line 29, here is line 29.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

Error:

> No signature of method: build_elagrqeqa0ondqjprsne9cg0n.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_elagrqeqa0ondqjprsne9cg0n$_run_closure2) values: [build_elagrqeqa0ondqjprsne9cg0n$_run_closure2@1795fa3f]

Comment: What gradle version are you using?  Have you tried flutter clean?

Comment: ı am using last version of gradle .ı tried anything but doesn't  work.

Comment: now ı have another similar problem problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_4bcfyw4syymz7augmelpbzhw0.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_4bcfyw4syymz7augmelpbzhw0$_run_closure2) values: [build_4bcfyw4syymz7augmelpbzhw0$_run_closure2@6be7a9d1]